# How can I set the mode of a QDateTimeElement using json?

Tags: quickdialog

I'm using QuickDialog to generate forms from JSON, all is well, other than the date/time picker. Unfortunately, the documentation does mention the different types of date pickers available. The sample source also produces forms from code, however I want to produce it using the JSON mechanism.

Here is an extract of my JSON. This only chooses the time only picker:

```
"elements": [
    {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"Date"}, // time only picker
    {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","mode":"UIDatePickerModeDate","title":"Date"}, // crashes
    {"type":"QDateTimeElement","title":"Date","date":"01/03/2013"}, // crashes
    {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"Date","mode":"1"}, // crashes
    {"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"Time"} // time only
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was close with the mode. This is what ended up giving me the date only when the form was built using json only:

```
{"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"Date","_mode":"1"}, //works
```

This works because the 1 is what the UIDatePickerModeDate value of UIDatePickerMode enum evaluates to.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of QRootBuilder there is a method called "initializeMappings".  This method has all JSON equivalent iOS mappings.

For Example:
{"type":"QDateTimeInlineElement","title":"Date","mode":"Date"}

Within the initializeMappings method "Date" corresponds to UIDatePickerModeDate